# user created jpanel getter does not update

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a minesweeper game with a JFrame. I set up the Menu and game in classes that extended the JPanel class. The problem is that when I try to get when a button is pressed and what is pressed with a getter, the main class only gets the initial value of the variable. What do I need to do to fix this problem?

the menu class

```
package mines;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/**
 * @author joshua
 */
public class Menu extends JPanel
{
    private JButton m1, m2, m3;
    private int width, height, widthOne, heightOne, choice;

    public Menu()
    {
        choice = 0;
        widthOne = 250;
        heightOne = 150;
        width = widthOne * 2;
        height = heightOne * 2;
        m1 = new JButton("Easy: 8X8 10 mines");
        m2 = new JButton("Medium: 16X16 40 mines");
        m3 = new JButton("Hard: 32X16 99 mines");
        m1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(widthOne, heightOne));
        m2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(widthOne, heightOne));
        m3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(widthOne, heightOne));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        add(m1);
        add(m2);
        add(m3);

        m1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                choice = 1;
            }
        }); 
        m2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                choice = 2;
            }
        }); 
        m3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                choice = 3;
            }
        }); 
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    public int getChoice()
    {
        return choice;
    }

    public void resetChoice()
    {
        choice = 0;
    }
}
```

the main class

```
package mines;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Main().go();
    }

    public void go()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Grid grid = new Grid(1);
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        frame.add(menu);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        boolean done = false;
        boolean menuBool = true;

        while(!done)
        {
            if(menuBool)
            {
                if(menu.getChoice() != 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("" + menu.getChoice());
                    grid = new Grid(menu.getChoice());
                    menu.resetChoice();
                    frame.add(grid);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(grid.atEnd())
                {
                    frame.add(menu);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an invalid game loop:

```
  while (!done) {
     if (menuBool) {
        if (menu.getChoice() != 0) {
           System.out.println("" + menu.getChoice());
           grid = new Grid(menu.getChoice());
           menu.resetChoice();
           frame.add(grid);
        }
     } else {
        if (grid.atEnd()) {
           frame.add(menu);
        }
     }
  }
```

This is not how event-driven Swing programs work. Instead react to events, to button presses, menu presses or changes in state, not while (true) loops that go forever and threaten to block the Swing event thread.

So in sum -- get rid of that loop and instead react to events with listeners such as ActionListeners added to your menu items or your buttons, when they are triggered.

For instance, Swing has support for PropertyChangeListeners and their support built in, and I suggest you consider using this. It could look something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Main().go();
   }

   public void go() {
      final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      final Grid grid = new Grid(1);
      final Menu menu = new Menu();

      // .... etc...
      frame.pack();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      boolean done = true; //!! was false
      boolean menuBool = true;

//      while (!done) {
//         // get rid of this 
//      }

      // instead do this -- add a property change listener to your menu JPanel
      menu.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
            if (Menu.CHOICE.equals(pcEvt.getPropertyName())) {
               System.out.println("Choice is: " + menu.getChoice());
            }
         }
      });
   }
}

class Menu extends JPanel {
   public static final String CHOICE = "choice";

   // each variable should get its own line
   private JButton m1
   private JButton m2;
   private JButton m3;
   private int width; 
   private int height;
   private int widthOne;
   private int heightOne;

   private int choice;  // declare each variable separately

   public Menu() {
      setChoice(0);
      widthOne = 250;

      // .... etc

      m1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setChoice(1);
         }
      });
      m2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setChoice(2);
         }
      });
      m3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setChoice(3);
         }
      });
   }
   //...
}
```

As an aside, I would avoid using magic numbers for my choices and instead use an enum. I'd also use a JComboBox instead of a bunch of buttons since the choices are mutually exclusive.